# mysqld won't connect to MySQL Cluster nor Data Nodes

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

I've created a v8.0MySQL cluster running on 4 VMs. VMs 1 & 2 have the MySQL and Cluster Manager daemon installed. VMs 3 & 4 have the Data Node daemon installed.

**Configuration of VMs:**

```
 ╓──────────────────────╥─────────────────────╥────────────────────╥────────────────────╖
 ║  [VM1]               ║ [VM2]               ║ [VM3]              ║  [VM4]             ║
 ║  10.103.0.11         ║ 10.103.0.12         ║ 10.103.0.23        ║  10.103.0.24       ║
 ║  mysql-clustermgr-01 ║ mysql-clustermgr-02 ║ mysql-datanode-01  ║  mysql-datanode-02 ║
 ║  ------------------- ║ ------------------- ║ ------------------ ║  ----------------- ║
 ║  mysqld  (NodeId=5)  ║ mysqld  (NodeId=6)  ║ ndbd (NodeId=3)    ║  ndbd (NodeId=4)   ║
 ║  ndb_mgmd(NodeId=1)  ║ ndb_mgmd(NodeId=2)  ║                    ║                    ║
 ╙──────────────────────╨─────────────────────╨────────────────────╨────────────────────╜
```

I have `ufw` disabled on all nodes to alleviate any FW issues. I can ping between all the servers in question without issue. All servers belong to the same subnet. I have set the permissions for `/etc/mysql` from `root:root` to `mysql:mysql`. I have tried several how-to's on the Internet that diagnose around mysqld not connecting.  Nothing seems to work over the last couple days. I have tried several configurations and this is as far as I can get with output from `ndb_mgm`:

```
emerg@mysql-clustermgr-01:~$ ndb_mgm -e show
Connected to Management Server at: mysql-clustermgr-01:1186
Cluster Configuration
---------------------
[ndbd(NDB)]     2 node(s)
id=3    @10.103.0.23  (mysql-8.0.28 ndb-8.0.28, starting, Nodegroup: 0)
id=4    @10.103.0.24  (mysql-8.0.28 ndb-8.0.28, starting, Nodegroup: 0)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 2 node(s)
id=1    @10.103.0.11  (mysql-8.0.28 ndb-8.0.28)
id=2    @10.103.0.12  (mysql-8.0.28 ndb-8.0.28)

[mysqld(API)]   2 node(s)
id=5 (not connected, accepting connect from mysql-clustermgr-01)
id=6 (not connected, accepting connect from mysql-clustermgr-02)
```

As you can see, the two cluster daemons can see each other just fine, however `mysqld` and `ndbd` on the data nodes refuse to connect/start respectively.

Here's my configuration files:

**[VM1] /etc/mysql/my.cnf**

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld]
ndbcluster

[mysql_cluster]
ndb-connectstring=NodeId=5,mysql-clustermgr-01,mysql-clustermgr-02
```

**[VM2] /etc/mysql/my.cnf**

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld]
ndbcluster

[mysql_cluster]
ndb-connectstring=NodeId=6,mysql-clustermgr-01,mysql-clustermgr-02
```

**[VM1 & VM2] /var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini**

```
[ndbd default]
NoOfReplicas=2
DataMemory=80M
DataDir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster

[ndb_mgmd]
HostName=mysql-clustermgr-01
DataDir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster
NodeId=1

[ndb_mgmd]
HostName=mysql-clustermgr-02
DataDir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster
NodeId=2

[ndbd]
HostName=mysql-datanode-01
NodeId=3
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data
LockExecuteThreadToCPU=1
LockMaintThreadsToCPU=0

[ndbd]
HostName=mysql-datanode-02
NodeId=4
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data

[mysqld]
HostName=mysql-clustermgr-01
NodeId=5

[mysqld]
HostName=mysql-clustermgr-02
NodeId=6
```

**[VM3] /etc/my.cnf**

```
[mysqld]
ndbcluster

[mysql_cluster]
ndb-connectstring=NodeId=3,mysql-clustermgr-01,mysql-clustermgr-02
```

**[VM4] /etc/my.cnf**

```
[mysqld]
ndbcluster

[mysql_cluster]
ndb-connectstring=NodeId=4,mysql-clustermgr-01,mysql-clustermgr-02
```

Services start fine, does anything within the configuration or architecture jump out at anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, you can't use hostnames, you have to use IPs in all config files. Man that set me back two days.